# How to Set App Icon as button On Dashboard in Odoo 14?

Tags: odoo

[image]

I want to set App icon on dashboard.
Then i click on sale App icon then redirect on sale Form.

Answer (score 2):

You must to specify the icon file in your module menu definitios as:

```
<menuitem name="mymenuname" id="myid" web_icon="mymodulename,static/src/img/app_icon.png"/>
```

Or you can specify the icon file in the menu definition on Odoo.

Here you can generate icons: https://spilymp.github.io/ibo/